# Loop through a list of xml-docs, save xpath tolist

Tags: xml, xpath

I got this method:

I call the method like this:

```
var gtin = GetListGT();
```

Hoping to select the values from the xpath into the list `gtin`

```
 public List<string> GetListGT()
        {
            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://www.dabas.com/mypages/search.aspx?typ=FP&sosokord=laggen");

            var xpath = "/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/table[9]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]";
            var gtin = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath) 
            ***Think i miss something here in order to add the info from the node to the list***
            return gtin.ToList();
        }
```

Can anyone see what i am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `return gtin.Select(n => n.InnerText).ToList();`.